# Remove border offset in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

```
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p><span style="border: 5px dotted blue; border-radius: 1em;">Hello</span></p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
```

As rendered in Chrome:

[image: As rendered in chrome]

When rendered, the border 'takes up space' and offsets the location of the content as well as increasing the size required for the content. Is there a way to make the border *not* do that? That is, have the border without any of the spacing/padding effects of the border?

The desired effect would be that the content is always in the same position whether or not it has a border (e.g. all the H in he above screenshot would have the same horizontal alignment). I can accept the border overlapping the content as well as extending outward, but if possible I would like to know how to do both.

I have considered making the border always present but transparent when not needed, however that makes spacing and padding quite a nuisance and I want to have borders of different sizes.

Note: I *am* able to use CSS3 and HTML5, if required.

Comment: `outline` does the same thing as border but doesn't take up any space.

Comment: @gp There doesn't seem to be an `outline-radius` though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a negative margin the same width as the border.

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p><span style="border: 5px dotted blue; border-radius: 1em; margin: -5px">Hello</span></p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insisted that the border has to be "over" the content, wanted a border-radius, not worried about how it looks, then you need to have overlapping html elements (extremely bad style, not recommended, but if that's what you want).

I have changed text to include one letter that goes below baseline, changed font size and border as solid to demonstrate, but all these can be changed to suit your needs.

```css
.border 
{
border: 5px solid blue;
border-radius: 1em;
position:relative;
top:-40px; /*double of font-size in p tag*/
color:transparent;
width:36px;
display:block;
font-size:10px;/*20px from original- 2 x border size*/
padding:0px;
}

.normal
{
width:40px;
font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<p class="normal">Hellq</p>
<p class="normal">Hellq</p>
<p class="normal">Hellq</p>
<span class="border">1</span>
<p class="normal">Hellq</p>
<p class="normal">Hellq</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, I mainly wanted to know out of curiosity.

Comment: In fact I did it out of the same reason :) as to how hard/bad it would get and to demonstrate that to anyone curious

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **outline** property.

```
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p><span style="outline: dashed blue; border-radius: 1em;">Hello</span></p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/outline

Comment: Ah I heard that CSS was changed to make the outline respect the border radius, looks like it doesn't have widespread browser support yet though. If you remind me when browser support is better I'll try and mark your answer as the accepted one.